# Container that can iterate in order, access specific elements, and remove elements

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, stdmap, stdset

I am currently using a `std::vector<int> vec` of size `n`to store the integers from 0 to `n-1` in any order. Suppose that the `vec` is given by the following:

```
std::vector<int> vec = {4, 1, 2, 0, 3};
```

I need to

- iterate over `vec` in order, i.e. 4 -> 1 -> 2 -> 0 -> 3.
- access specific elements by index `vec[3]` -> 0.
- remove specific elements by value `del vec[2]` -> `{4, 1, 0, 3}`.

The vector is given a priori and the maximum size is known (as we never *add* elements). What data structure would be suitable here (having performance in mind)?

Comment: Did you try and use `std::vector`? Did you have any issues with it?

Comment: That is impossible to tell. What do you mean by performance? How often do you do each operation? How big is `n`? And equally pertinent, why do you need the numbers in the first place?

Comment: The only one other than `std::vector` that could be worth benchmarking is `std::deque`, I think. For big numbers of elements It should make removing cheaper, but random access and  iteration are more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `std::vector`, it has the least overhead and isn't asymptoticly worse at any of these.

> iterate over vec in order

Any container will be at least linear in the number of elements.

> access specific elements by index

`std::vector` is constant here

> remove specific elements by value

Because you don't know where any given element is, and therefore have to do a search, which is worst case linear, every container will be worst case linear for this, so it doesn't matter that vector has linear erase.